# How to loop through a list, follow a hyperlink, and delete the corresponding worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, macros

I have a workbook that contains about 150 worksheets.  The first worksheet is a table/list of information that is about 150 rows long and 16 columns wide and is named "log".  In col. 'j' of the "log" worksheet are cell values that are either contain new or closed.  In col. 'm' are hyperlinks to other worksheets in the workbook.  The goal of the code is to go through each row of the "log" sheet and identify if it contains closed in col. j. If yes, follow the corresponding hyperlink, in the same row, and delete the sheet.  The issue is that I have situations where the hyperlink is shared by multiple rows.  For instance, row 5 hyperlinks to sheet 2 and row 15 hyperlinks to sheet 2. My issue is that when the code comes to row 15 and goes to follow the hyperlink there is nothing to follow, thus, the "log" is the active sheet and the "log" ends up getting deleted and my code then bombs out.  Is there a way to write code that says that if the active sheet is the log sheet to not delete it or skip the code that is currently in place to delete a sheet and instead continue the loop?

Here is the code...

```
Sub Deletelinks()

'Macro will check to see if status is closed and if so it will
'delete the supporting worksheet by following the hyperlink in
'same row

Dim count As Integer
Dim lrow As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("J2")
lrow = Worksheets("log").Range("J" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row - 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For count = 1 To lrow
    Sheets("log").Activate
    Rng.Offset(count - 1, 0).Activate
    Select Case ActiveCell.Value = "Closed"
        Case True
            If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Click" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
                If ActiveSheet.Name <> "log" Then
                    With ActiveSheet
                        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.delete
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Case False
    End Select
 Next count


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: I would have expected that your line saying `If ActiveSheet.Name <> "log" Then` would already be stopping the sheet named "log" from being deleted.  Is it actually named "log"?  Or is it perhaps called "Log"?

Comment: If row 2 and row 15 both have hyperlinks to Sheet2, and row 2 says "Closed" but row 15 says "Open", are you expecting Sheet2 to be deleted or kept?  (Or will this be a non-issue because both rows should have the same status?)

Comment: The 'if ActiveSheet.name <> "log" then' part of my code never seems to work.  I thought it would but it basically was ignored. I'm not sure why it wasn't working but that is then why I asked the question.

To answer your other question, it should be a non-issue as they should be the same.

It appears Thomas' code below is as he said a simpler approach and works just fine. Thanks

Comment: Testing for `"log"` won't work if the sheet is called `"Log"` or `"LOG"` due to the uppercase characters, so I was just wondering whether something simple like that was causing your issue.  (I was also thinking of other non-obvious differences, such as `"0"` instead of `"o"`, or a trailing space in the sheet name, but they would stop `Worksheets("log")` from working, so it couldn't be those sort if differences.)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be to iterate over the hyperlinks in the column and use the hyperlink's properties to reference the adjacent cell to see if it equals `Closed`; then if it does, delete the hyperlinks target worksheet and clear the hyperlink.

```
Sub DeleteLinks()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim link As Hyperlink
    For Each link In Worksheets("log").Columns("M").Hyperlinks

        If link.Range.Offset(0, -3) = "Closed" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Range(link.SubAddress).Parent.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
            link.Range.ClearContents
        End If

    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Thomas.  This is simpler and does exactly what I needed.